# Where do I find boating rules for 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, vehicles

Where do I find boat/ship rules for D&D 4e? Guidance for skill challenges using boats as well as combat on boats greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a watery skill challenge — "The Rushing River" — in the **DMG2** (page 94) that could provide some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a fair number of boat/ship oriented encounters in Living Forgotten Realms adventures. Sometimes the ships are airships, but I think that's still useful. Specific adventures:

- MOON 1-1 (Nature's Wrath) has a combat that takes place on a ship
- MOON 1-7 (Treasure Hunt) is set on a ship, and has a number of aquatic encounters
- MOON 2-1 (Darkness Falls Over Moray) has a skill challenge for surviving a shipwreck
- CORE 2-3 (High Infidelity) has several airship combats; this is a paragon tier adventure
- CORE 2-10 (Upon the Sea of Stars) likewise has airship combats; it's a sequel to High Infidelity
- MINI 2-1 (A Mourning of Ravens) is largely land-locked, but the initial encounter and combat takes place on a ship
- WATE 1-4 (The Mystery of Deepwater Harbor) involves a shipwreck, including an underwater encounter on the ship
- WATE 1-5 (Lost in the Fog) has a skill challenge to recover items from a shipwreck

This implies the question "how do I get LFR adventures?" which is a really painful question because the answer is not simple. [This thread](http://community.wizards.com/lfr/go/thread/view/76817/25782529/How_to_find_adventures.) may prove handy. Hopefully this fall the process will become easier.

My favorite papercrafting board had this question [recently](http://fatdragongames.proboards.com/index.cgi?action=display&board=general&thread=1515&page=1), and came up with a lot more good stuff. Summarized (but check out the thread as well):

- The 4e [Freeport Companion](http://www.rpgnow.com/product_info.php?products_id=77793)
- A free [Nautical Compendium](http://implementgames.webs.com/nauticalcompendium.htm)
- WotC [forum thread](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/24042809/Seafaring_adventuring_in_4E?pg=1) on seafaring

Comment: Wow, I should get me an RPGA number someday

Comment: Your somewhat friendly local gaming store has cards. LFR has been largely decoupled from WotC supervision, so sometime in the next three months the process for downloading adventures will become much much easier, thankfully; you may or may not need a membership at that point. But it's a great source of self-contained one-shot 4e adventures either way.